# Run msdeploy.exe from under DefaultAppPool produces weird behaviour

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment, msdeploy, application-pool

### Intro

I have this **ASP.NET** web app and I'd like to provide its users a way to update the app via POST request with **zip** file which contains the newer version of the app.

While successefully receiving, storing and using the zip file, I found that [**`msdeploy.exe`**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) program does not work, meaning my app is not getting updated.

I am using the following command line syntax:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package={0} -dest:auto -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

*(where {0} is replaced by enquoted full path to the zip file)*

### The issue

While **successefully installing** the update via Windows© Shell manually, I **fail to do so** when I start `msdeploy` from withing my web application. The code I'm using:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = Path.Combine(workingDir, "msdeploy.exe"),
    WorkingDirectory = workingDir,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = @"-verb:sync -source:package={0} -dest:auto -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -verbose".Formatted(filename.Enquote()),
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
};

Process deploy = Process.Start(info);
deploy.Start();
```

### Debugging attempts

I have redirected the program's output into a file so I could compare it to the **ideal** one, the manual way one which actually works.

Working `msdeploy` output (run via my windows account + windows shell):

```
Info: Updating file (Default Web Site/ElQueue\bin\AutoMapper.dll).
Info: Updating file (Default Web Site/ElQueue\bin\Contracts.dll).
...
Info: Updating file (Default Web Site/ElQueue\Views\Web.config).
Info: Updating file (Default Web Site/ElQueue\Web.config).
Info: Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/ElQueue)
Info: Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/ElQueue)
Total changes: 27 (1 added, 0 deleted, 26 updated, 0 parameters changed, 803122 bytes copied)
```

Non-working `msdeploy` output (run via `Process.Start` hence [IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) IIS' virtual account):

```
Warning: BACKUP_FAILED - Skipping backup because it failed due to an unknown reason.яFor more information, contact your server administrator.
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Info: Creating application (Default Web Site/ElQueue)
```

And, that's all. Not much. No file updates, no nothing. The application's files remain unchanged.

### SO, how to update my web app **the right way**?

I thought msdeploy is the way, but its seems not to work with default IIS app pool.

Comment: Could this be permissions based? You say it works using your windows account but not via the app so it feels like the app does not have execute permissions perhaps?  You could try calling `Process.Start` and pass in your credentials to test this (use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat(v=vs.110).aspx)  Do you get anything in the server event log?

Comment: Try adding MachineName\IUSR to the local administrators group (If you don't want to do this, try installing the web management service and setting up iis manager permissions on the target site); Also make sure you run your upload site under a different App Pool.

Comment: @badazzhindu i did that and the result remain unchanged.

Comment: @philreed With `Process.Start` and my credentials there is no log inside a output stream, its just **empty** while the result is the same. it is like msdeploy starts and immediately closes without saying anything. Server event **log** doesn't contain any informatino according to the update attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding a **`IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`** user into `Administrators` group via `lusrmgr.msc` management console tool and also reboot after that.

Answer (score 1):

How do you authenticate your users? If it's Windows authentication the best option would be to configure [Web deployment delegation rule](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler). Making your pool account identity part of local Administrators may have serious security issues.

Comment: In this case I'd create a separate pool for the site and then configure a rule in Management Service Delegation for the pool identity. So, after you authenticate your user you can deploy an uploaded package via Web Deploy API (the call will be using the security context of the pool account). This method is more complex but also safer.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right, but it seems I cannot install the management service though I read articles how to do that (may be its because im running windows 7 embedded). Also, could you provide a link to deploy API?